# Security test for AES

Tags: c#, security, encryption, aes

I dont know how to start this but I want to know if how am I gonna test how secured my program specifically the application of AES which I just copied on MSDN.

I'm no expert at application security, neither much knowledge about the security issues.

Much better if there are software that automatically do it for me.

This is the code I copied:

```
static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create an AesManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }


        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

That code just uses AES/CBC. That's fine providing *confidentiality* for data at rest. As usual it leaks information about the input length.

Furthermore, it doesn't provide integrity or authenticity, so anybody can change the ciphertext. This means that if this is a valid attack scenario that parts of the plaintext will come out garbled.

It doesn't provide any protection within transport protocols by itself. It's pretty easy to even leak the entire plaintext due to padding oracle attacks.

---

The key should be *derived* from a password using a password hash such as PBKDF2 or it should be randomly generated.

If you reuse the key for CBC then the IV should be non-predictable (by using a secure random generator). The IV is usually put in front of the ciphertext.

The code doesn't show any of these properties.

---

In other words, it depends very much on the use and possible attack vectors if the code above is secure or not. AES is secure, but that in itself doesn't provide any protection.

The code is AES/CBC, nothing more, nothing less. If you don't understand crypto and you copy code, even from Microsoft, the chances are slim that you will end up with *any* kind of security.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence.  Copying and pasting security-related code is akin to shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: The program will be run on LAN through ClickOnce and only must use AES. I dont know my way out here. Can I just ask for snippet code that I can just edit the key? I really hate spoon-feeding but it just the time is not cooperating.